# How to output a chunk or message if getPage is empty in MODX Revo 2.x

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I have this construction:

```
[[!getPage? 
&element=`getResources` 
&limit=`10` 
&tpl=`vacancy_tpl` 
&parents=`[[*id]]` 
&includeContent=`1` 
&includeTVs=`1` 
&showHidden=`1` 
&pageFirstTpl=`<li class="control"><a[[+classes]][[+title]] href="[[+href]]">First</a></li>` 
&pageLastTpl=`<li class="control"><a[[+classes]][[+title]] href="[[+href]]">Last</a></li>
`]]
```

How can I output a message or chunk if there are **no results** returned by `getPage` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easier way to do it, just use [modx input/output filters](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Input+and+Output+Filters+%28Output+Modifiers%29) -

```
[[!getPage:empty=`<div>[[$your_chunk]] or your message</div>`? 
    &element=`getResources` 
    &limit=`10` 
    &tpl=`vacancy_tpl` 
    &parents=`[[*id]]` 
    &includeContent=`1` 
    &includeTVs=`1` 
    &showHidden=`1` 
    &pageFirstTpl=`<li class="control"><a[[+classes]][[+title]] href="[[+href]]">First</a></li>` 
    &pageLastTpl=`<li class="control"><a[[+classes]][[+title]] href="[[+href]]">Last</a></li>
`]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is on [Solution for: How output chunk or message if getPage is empty in MODX Revo 2.x](http://forums.modx.com/thread/93218/how-output-chunk-or-message-if-getpage-is-empty-in-modx-revo-2-x)

Thanks for help to [Erhard](http://forums.modx.com/u/erhard).